# Lambda expression inside ?? (if shortcut) operator

Tags: c#, if-statement, lambda

I like short code, so recently I was trying to fit if statement and Linq query with lambda expression in one line.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
db.Users.First(x => x.UserId == providedId)??x.SomeUsefullField
```

That should return null if user not found, and value of some field if user does exists.

Is it possible to do without first getting user and than getting field value like this:

```
var user = db.Users.First(x => x.UserId == providedId);
var fieldValue = user.SomeUsefullField;
```

Thank you for possible solution and knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the null propagation operator:

```
var userField = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == providedId)?.SomeUsefullField;
```

Important here is to use `FirstOrDefault`, which will return `null` when no match is found. Then use `?.` to only get the `SomeUsefullField` property when the expression doesn't return `null`.

Comment: yet another c# 'innovation' that leads to less readable code!

Comment: Indeed, not everyone is happy with these improvements, I however do like to use it for simple conditions. @MitchWheat

Comment: Thanks, will mark as correct answer when timer allow to do. Unfortunately I need to use C# 5 in that project so wont be able to use that method. But when we will move to next version of C# I will keep that method in mind. About code readability...sometimes there is very short encapsulated methods with very good name that doing one simple thing, so it ok to make it short. And sometimes I put each variable to separate line to provide more visualization on flow.